# Criteria Showing list size 1 when there are no records

Tags: java, hibernate

I have the doubt regarding the hibernate criteria.

I'm getting list size as 1 when there are no records in the list.When i print the list it shown as list[null].

My code:

```
final Double depositAmount = (Double)session.createCriteria(vardhanDep.class)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("userDetByCrtbyUserid", userid))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("delflag","0"))
        .setProjection(Projections.sum("amount"))
        .list().get(0);
```

Help me to solve this issue

Comment: That seems like exactly what it should do.  What is the issue?  What is it you want it to do?  Also, seeing an IEEE floating point representation used for something called deposit is somewhat alarming :)

Comment: I agree with Affe regarding the fact that using a floating point type, in your case Double, for something that has to do with money, is rather alarming. What Affe and I are referring to is the fact that floating points don't always represent the exact number you think it does, and that it sometimes represents the closest possible floating point instead of the number you think it does. For instance, if you define your double to be 0.9, it actually will be the closest possible double, which is 0.8999999999999999. When it comes to money, this can of course be scary. Use Bigdecimal instead.

Comment: By the way, if you use BigDecimal, use the *String* constructor and not the *double* constructor as else you will run into the same kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Affe already mentions, this is exactly as expected. The *Projections.sum* is actually a so called aggregate projection, meaning it will do an aggregation (like a *group by* in SQL) on all returned records. The *Projections.sum* in your example therefore calculates the sum of the *amount* field in all returned records (meaning all records that match your criteria). Even if no records match your criteria, the aggregation will calculate the sum, which will of course be '0', as there is nothing to sum up. The projection will therefore always return a record, and also always only one record, despite the amount of records that match your criteria.

Comment: what i dont is i checked list.get(0)!=null then i accessed that element